# using curl with ${=(System.nanoTime())} inside req.xml file

Tags: curl, xml

i want to be able generating system nano second sequence when using curl

my code is like this:

> curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d  @req.xml server_URL >
>   result.xml

the req.xml contains the following:

```
<MessageSeq>${=(System.nanoTime())}</MessageSeq>
```

so the expected value in request should be like:

> 2163586109424686

but instead it is giving me:

> ${=(System.nanoTime())}

any way to convert it into system timer, in nanoseconds.

Comment: Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: because in soapui it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, cURL does not have a native mechanism for value interpolation. However, you can use some `sed` magic to substitute:

```
sed "s/\${TIME}/$(date +%s%N)/g" req.xml | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -d @- server.tld > result.xml
```

The `date` command will output the current time in the format specified. `%s` is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch, and `%N` is the number of nanoseconds of the current second.

In bash, `$(...)` in a `"`-quoted string will insert the output of a command in a parameter of another. This will generate a sed command that replaces all instances of `${TIME}` with the current time. The curl parameter `-d @-` makes it read the POST data from stdin. While you can keep the syntax of each expression, I don't think it's worthwhile.

Comment: thanks dear it really works fine after manipulating req.xml using sed